# setString on nil object with categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

It looks to me like sending `setString:` to a `NSMutableString` that hasn't had `init` called on it yet does not call `init` on it's own.  For example:

```
NSMutableString *string;   // Declare, but do not init yet
[string setString:@"foo"];
NSLog (@"%@",string);      // Prints "(null)"
```

I'd like to overwrite this behavior, so that essentially

```
- (void) setString:(NSString *)aString
{
    if (!self)
    {
        self = [self initWithString:aString];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setString:aString];
    }
}
```

I could do so with a subclass, but I would have to go through my project and replace all my `NSMutableString`s with my subclass, which is a pain.  I was looking at the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) and it looks like what I want to do is create a Category for `NSMutableString`.  I haven't used categories before, so I got a couple questions:

First, it looks like categories only allow me to add new methods, it doesn't allow me to overwrite existing methods.  I suppose it is easy enough to just create a `setStringWithInit:` method that does what I want, so this first issue isn't really an issue after all (although I still have to do a find-replace through my project for `setString`, but oh well).

Second, and more importantly, how do I check if the sender of my new method is `nil`?  If  `setString:` returned something other than `void`, I think I could get it to work, but that's not the case here.  How do I get the `if (!self)` check from my code above to work with a category?

Or are categories not the way to go for this kind of thing, and I'd just be better off sub-classing after all?

EDIT:
So the strings I'm using this on will actually be `@property`s of a custom `NSObject` subclass.  In my code, I'll actually be calling `[myObject.someProperty setString:@"foo"];`, and the debugger is showing me that `someProperty` is nil when I try to do this.  Also, in other parts of my app I'm checking `if (!myObject.someProperty)` to see if that property has been used yet, so I don't want to just automatically `self.someProperty = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` in the `init` method of `myObject`'s class.

Although now that I think about it, I think I can get away with replacing `if (!myObject.someProperty)` with `if ([myObject.someProperty length] == 0)`, which would allow me to go through and alloc-init things right away.  But if I'm initializing everything right away, that will create some memory space for it, correct?  It's probably negligible though.  Hm, perhaps this is what I should be doing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macros FTW!

```
#define setString(X,Y) if(!X){X=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:Y];}else{[X setString:Y];}
```

When I try to assign a value with this:

- It will always be initialized first
- It won't be initialized until I try to give it a value
- It doesn't clutter up my code
- It still gives a warning if X isn't an `NSMutableString`, or if Y isn't an `NSString` or `NSMutableString`
- I haven't tested for if `Y` is `nil`, but I expect it will cause a crash, which is what I want.

Drawbacks:

- I still have to remember to always use my `setString()` instead of the stock `setString:`
- I'll have to do something similar for any other setters I call (the only one that I'm worried about off hand is `setValue:forKey:`, which I use extensively - one step at a time I guess) - a one size fits all solution would have been nice - maybe a topic for another question.
- Whatever I pass in has to be a `NSString` before I pass it, I cannot convert it to a string in line - but at least I get a build error if I try to do so, so it isn't up to me to remember to do so (still adds clutter though)

  `NSMutableString *X;`

  `int y = 0;`

  `setString(X, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y])   // <--- Doesn't work`

  `NSString *Y = [NSStirng stringWithFormat:@"%d",y];`

  `setString(X,Y)                                      // <--- Does work`

Answer (score 3):

The proper code would simply be:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
[string setString:@"foo"];
NSLog (@"%@",string);
```

Why would you not initialize the variable? There is no need to override `setString:` or any other method. Don't try to treat `NSMutableString` any differently than any other class.

Besides, overriding `setString:` still won't solve anything. As long as the pointer is `nil` you can't call a method on it.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that you can't call a method on a pointer to `nil`, I haven't tried before.  As for why I'm doing this, I edited my Question.  I may have also supplied my own answer though.

Comment: @GeneralMike: You can actually send *any* message to nil, but nil responds to any message by returning itself. Your core issue here is just that you have nil instead of an NSMutableString, so nothing NSMutableString does can make a difference. That's why you assign `[NSMutableString string]` — because then you have a string to talk to.

Answer (score 1):

You can reimplement a method without subclassing by using **method swizzling**. Here's [a tutorial](http://ioscodesnippet.com/2013/02/17/method-swizzling-in-objective-c/). There are 2 reasons not to do it here though.

1. it would be against the good Objective-C practices, since your
   setter will also be an init method. Not good.
2. As @**rmaddy** correctly points out, calling `setString:` on a nil object will do
   nothing. Even if you do override the method.

So I recommend creating a category on `NSMutableString`, and implementing `[NSMutableString initWithString:]` there. It is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Hm, I guess I don't see why 1. is such a bad thing.  I feel that if I want to assign a value to a variable, I want that variable to exist.  In fact, I guess I'm surprised that you can try to assign a value to something that doesn't exist, and it doesn't even give you a warning or anything - it just silently doesn't do what I want it to do, and I can't really think of anything more dangerous than that.

Comment: When you say `So I recommend ... in your category instead...`, did you mean to say `...in your code instead of setString:, and don't create a category at all...`?  The rest of your answer sounds like you think the category idea is a bad way to go, but then you recommend doing it at the end.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @GeneralMike I recommend creating a category and defining `initWithString:` there. I don't recommend using swizzling for what want to do. I've edited my answer for clarify :)

Comment: Re. your first comment. I see why you might want this behavior in this particular example. But in a more general case, if calling a method on a nil object were to create that object, that'd lead to all kinds of unexpected behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about calling ANY method creating a new object, but I thought perhaps setters could be treated differently.  I forgot that setters are just like any other method, when you really get into the details.  Interesting...

Comment: Re. your other comment, `initWithString:` is already defined, so I could not create a category with the same name, correct?  So are you saying just use `initWithString:` everywhere I'm currently using `setString:`?  What if the object does already exist - are there any concerns with calling an `init` method that has already been initialized?

Comment: You may use `initWithString:` everywhere, as long as you're aware that it will create a new object every time. I think it's not very clean though (not to mention the overhead of reallocating objects every time you assign a new value). So I'd prefer to check if the object is nil before initing it again. That adds an extra line of code or two, but I think it's worth it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that now, it just really clutters up the code, and I have to remember to do it every time I want to use a setter, which makes it a little error prone.

Comment: @GeneralMike: I think the core problem here is that you're confusing variables and objects. When you write `NSMutableString *foo;`, you're **not** creating an NSMutableString — you're just creating a variable. You can think of variables as index cards that contain directions to look up an object. When you write `NSMutableString *foo;`, you're just saying "Make an index card and I'll write the directions to an NSMutableString on it later." Without the directions, it's just a blank card. `[[NSMutableString alloc] init]` creates an NSMutableString object, and `=` writes its location on the card.

Answer (score 1):

You are marching down a path to madness. Abandon hope, all ye who enter here!

Do not try to change the language semantics so that sending a message to a nil object somehow magically creates an instance of the object. That is not how the language works.

What you are trying to do is likely impossible, and if you were able to succeed, you would create programs that are fundamentally incompatible with standard Objective-C. You might as well found a new language, Objective-D

It is legal to send a message to a nil object in Objective C. The result is that the message gets silently dropped, and nothing happens. In many other object-oriented other languages, sending a message to a nil object/zero pointer causes a crash.

The semantics of of Objective C object creation are:

First allocate memory for the object using the class method alloc:

```
NSMutableString* aString = [NSMutableString alloc];
```

Then send the newly created object an init method to set it to its initial state:

```
aString = [aString init];
```

These 2 steps are just about always combined into a single line:

```
NSMutableString* aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Classes sometimes include shortcut "convenience" methods that do the 2 step alloc/init for you, and return an object in one call, e.g.:

```
NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 50];
```

Do not try to fight this convention. Learn to follow it. If you cannot tolerate this convention, program in a different language. Really.

Comment: If "program in a different language" was an option, I would have done so long ago ;).  Unfortunately, my customers want apps for the iPad, and from what I understand, if you want to write an app for the iPad, you have to write it in Obj-C (or some version of C).  But I was getting the impression I was trying to do something I'm not supposed to, thanks for confirming that suspicion.

Comment: FWIW, I'd be fine with sending messages to nil objects causing a crash, at least then I'd know something went wrong and I could start looking to find out what.  As it is now, I have to trust that my testers realize that the app is performing strangely - and for what I'm writing this app to do, that's not a good assumption to make.  If I think I'm adding 2 numbers together, but they don't get added together because that addition was supposed to be done by a nil object, it might slip by unnoticed.  I don't suppose there is an option I change somewhere that will force crashes though, is there?

Comment: If you depend for an object to be non-nil somewhere in your code, you can add an assert to catch it: `NSAssert(string != nil, @"expected a valid string here!");`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do that - you have a method which can be called only on instance of this object, so you will have to create it first anyways to use it.

In your code it will be "nil" anyways - it won't create itself.

Why are you doing it instead of just:

```
NSMutableString *string = @foo";
```

I cannot imagine a reason to avoid allocating an object

Comment: You can't assign an `NSString` to a variable of type `NSMutableString`.